# How come this stripe request doesn't set a customer's description to null?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am attempting to set the description of a customer in Stripe to `null` using PHP, but am currently unable to.

Stripe's API Docs for `description`

> This can be unset by updating the value to null and then saving.

I am attempting to use Laravel's `tinker` to do this.

```
>>> $customer = Customer::retrieve('cus_AgcMLZIYr2XIZm');
=> Stripe\Customer {#891}
>>> $customer->description;
=> "Test"
>>> Customer::update('cus_AgcMLZIYr2XIZm', ['description' => null]);
=> Stripe\Customer {#888}
>>> $customer = Customer::retrieve('cus_AgcMLZIYr2XIZm');
=> Stripe\Customer {#852}
>>> $customer->description;
=> "Test"
>>>
```

How come the customer's description didn't get set to null? I expected it to, but when I retrieve it again it is still set. The customer's description **does** change if I pass a string.

Are Stripe's docs wrong (seems absurd, but I expected this to work)?

Comment: maybe the `cus_AgcMLZIYr2XIZm`  doesn't support null, have you try something else. like "a text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the library can't tell the difference between `null` and the value not being set at all. This will work as expected if you pass an empty string `''` for the description instead of null, or if you instead do:

```
 $customer = Customer::retrieve("cus_AgcMLZIYr2XIZm");
 $customer->description = null;
 $customer->save();
```

Comment: This works, but does not work with `$customer->shipping->address->country = null;` Can you not do that?